# Bug or feature when creating custom .onFormSubmit trigger while using Google's Team Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In the following code:

```
function CreateandUpdateForm() {
  Logger.log("Hi");
}


function onFormSumbit(e) {
  var formid = "MyFormIDCode"
  var functionName = "CreateandUpdateForm"
  var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).forForm(formid).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

Typically in this script, I would run `onFormSubmit(e)` once and this creates a custom trigger. Then everytime I hit submit on my form the action is performed (in this case `Logger.log("Hi");`.

This works beautifully if I use my GSuite personal Google Drive, creating the custom trigger and firing it every time a form submission happens however if I use the identical script in a Google Team Drive, I get an error.

> Action not allowed (line 9, file "Code")

By commenting out each section I found that it was the .create() clause it objected to. Is this an expected result of using Google Team Drive or a bug? I've checked API access and best I can tell, everything is enabled that should be enabled

Comment: I could be wrong about this but when I create triggers like that I always check to make sure that there isn't already a trigger with that funcname.  I use code like this: `function isTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}` To avoid creating multiple triggers.

Comment: I do not know any specifics about the Team Drive situation with Google Forms and the On Submit trigger, but I do know that many people have not been able to make it work in a team drive.  I tell people to move the Form out of the team drive to get it to work.  But again, I don't know the details of why or if this is expected behavior.